# Facebook video calling problem in Safari

Tags: macos, safari, facebook

I have a little issue with Safari. I can't make video calls with Facebook Messenger in Safari. I know that with Google Chrome or Firefox we can avoid this problem, but as you know Safari is optimized for macOS.

I've tried to use a user's agent but it doesn't work. Is there a way to use the Facebook video calling feature with Safari?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Facebook video calling is not supported on Safari (and hasn't been for years).

Apple hasn't indicated they will support this nor has Facebook indicated they would change their code to accommodate Safari.

Your options are to provide feedback [to Apple](https://www.apple.com/feedback/safari.html) or [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/268228883256323), telling them you'd like this feature supported.

Comment: Thanks. I hope that Safari 13 can avoid this issue.

Comment: @LuisMiguel I haven't seen/heard anything in the iOS 13 betas that this has been addressed.  I could be wrong, of course, so we'll see in a few months when it comes out.